# Relacion entre usuario(1) y (n)personajes en mongodb. Estaria bien de este modo?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Buenas quisiera relacionar 2 **schemas** en mongodb mediante nodejs.

La **relacion** es la siguiente : 'Un usuario puede tener n personajes'.

**Schema usuario**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const {Schema} = mongoose;


const usuarioSchema = new Schema({
    nombre_personal :{type: String, required : true},
    apel1_personal :{type: String, required : true},
    apel2_personal :{type: String, required : true},
    pais :{type: String, required : true},
    ciudad :{type: String, required : true},
    nombre_usuario :{type: String, required : true},
    password_usuario :{type: String, required : true},
    email_usuario :{type: String, required : true}


});

module.exports = mongoose.model('USUARIOS', usuarioSchema);
```

**Schema personajes**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const {Schema} = mongoose;


const personajeSchema = new Schema({
    nombre :{type: String, required : true},
    apellidos :{type: String, required : true},
    mundo :{type: String, required : true},
    lugar_mundo :{type: String, required : true},
    raza :{type: String, required : true},
    edad :{type: Number, required : true},
    clase :{type: String, required : true},
    oficio :{type: String, required : true},
    historia :{type: String, required : true},
    personajes_creados:{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'USUARIOS'}

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('PERSONAJES', personajeSchema);
```

**¿Es correcto poner en el schema 'usuarios' la referencia a personajes o tendria que ser al reves, en personajes hacer referencia al usuario?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La relación que deseas implementar es ***1:n***, tal que ***Un usuario puede tener n personajes***, indica que en tu modelo Usuarios debes tener una referencia al modelo Personajes.

Primero deseo aclararte que el concepto de ***Esquema*** (Schema) es exclusivo de Mongoose y no de MongoDB. Mongoose utiliza este concepto para abstraer el modelado de las colecciones en MongoDB y sus relaciones, permitiendo una mayor flexibilidad y simplicidad para tratar con los datos almacenados en la BD.

Dicho esto, tu relación ***1:n*** puede quedar de la siguiente forma: (suelo usar ES6)

```
//archivo: user.model.js
//ES6
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

//ES5
//const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nombre_personal :{type: String, required : 'Campo NOMBRE es requerido'},
    apel1_personal :{type: String, required : 'Campo PRIMER APELLIDO es requerido'},
    apel2_personal :{type: String},  // No se si es necesario el segundo apellido como REQUIRED, hay personas con un solo apellido.
    pais :{type: String, required : 'Campo PAIS es requerido'},
    ciudad :{type: String, required : 'Campo CIUDAD es requerido'},
    nombre_usuario :{type: String, required : 'Campo USERNAME es requerido'},
    password_usuario :{type: String, required : 'Campo PASSWORD es requerido'},
    email_usuario :{type: String, required : 'Campo EMAIL es requerido'},
    personajes: [{
        id: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Personaje' } // aqui establecemos la relación con nuestro modelo Personaje
    }]
});

export default mongoose.model('Usuario', userSchema);

//ES5
//module.exports = mongoose.model('Usuario', userSchema);
```

Como puedes ver, hemos creado un campo llamado ***personajes*** en nuestro modelo *Usuario*, el cual contiene un array con documentos (objetos) que contienen una referencia directa al modelo *Personaje*.

De esta forma tienes la relación ***1:n*** que estás buscando.

Tu modelo ***Personaje*** puede quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
// archivo: personaje.model.js
//ES6
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

//ES5
//const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const personajeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nombre :{type: String, required : 'El campo NOMBRE es requerido'},
    apellidos :{type: String, required : 'El campo APELLIDOS es requerido'},
    mundo :{type: String, required : 'El campo MUNDO es requerido'},
    lugar_mundo :{type: String, required : 'El campo LUGAR es requerido'},
    raza :{type: String, required : 'El campo RAZA es requerido'},
    edad :{type: Number, required : 'El campo EDAD es requerido'},
    clase :{type: String, required : 'El campo CLASE es requerido'},
    oficio :{type: String, required : 'El campo OFICIO es requerido'},
    historia :{type: String, required : 'El campo HISTORIA es requerido'}
});

export default mongoose.model('Personaje', personajeSchema);

//ES5
//module.exports = mongoose.model('Personaje', personajeSchema);
```

Como puedes ver he quitado la referencia que tenías al modelo *Usuario*

Una de las cosas que también puedes observar es que he cambiado el nombre de los modelos, ya que el modelo se refiere a un documento no a varios. De esta forma habrá una mayor coherencia semántica cuando te refieras a tus datos. Lo mismo ocurre con el modelo *Personaje*, ya que el modelo se refiere a un solo documento.

Espero que sea la respuesta que estabas buscando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la toda esta valiosa informacion , me gustaria preguntarte una cosa. SI esto fuese en una Base de Datos relacional tendriamos que crear en la tabla personajes un id del propietario, por lo que estoy viendo en mongoose es al reves no ? en la 'tabla' padre pones un campo del hijo. Es justamente al reves que en una BD relacional no ? 
De nuevo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. !!

Comment: Creo que confundes una BD relacional con una que no lo es. Recuerda que en MongoDB, al no ser una BD *relacional* no puedes aplicar el concepto de *relaciones* tal como lo haces en una BD relacional (MySQL, SQL Server, etc.)

Comment: Si deseas convertir esto a una BD relacional, entonces debes crear una relación entre tablas y (dependiendo de tu modelo de datos) podrías tener un campo en la *tabla* Personajes que guarde una relación con la tabla Usuarios. Como dije, eso va a depender de tu modelo de datos.

Comment: Último comentario: puedes leer este [Post](https://carlosazaustre.es/como-relacionar-tus-modelos-en-mongodb/) donde se explica en pocas palabras un forma de relacionar documentos en MongoDB usando mongoose. Saludos

Comment: Muchas Gracias Mauricio, ya habia visto esa pagina. Muchas gracias por todo

Comment: Mauricio otra duda, mira ya tengo las relaciones hechas y tal, todo perfecto, ahora por ejemplo te pongo un caso: tengo un **usuario** creado y dos **personajes** . En este momento el **usuario**  tiene el array de de **personajes** vacio. Para crear una funcion que añada un **personaje** a un **usuario**  lo tendria que hacer en los **controladores del usuario** como seria ??? Un cordial saludo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91371/discussion-between-mauricio-contreras-and-josanangel).