# Como referenciar tablas en MongoDB (Usuario,Comentario)

Tags: json, mongodb

En MySql seria asi :

```
Usuarios
_id
*Nombre
*Apellido
*Correo

Comentarios
_id
*Comentarios
*Fecha
*id_Usu
```

En mySql seria que un usuario puede realizar varios comentarios pero 1 comentario le pertence a un usuario lo que significa que 1 a Muchos. 1 => Usuario y Muchos => Comentarios.

---

Pero no se como hacer este tipo de referencia en MongoDB

```
usuario = {
     _id : Id_Object,
     nombre : luis,
     apellido : ruiz,
     correo : qqqqqqqq@gmail.com
}

Comentarios = {
     _id : Id_Object,
     Comentarios : string,
     Fecha : Date.now,
     
}
```

No tengo idea como relacionar los comentarios que realiza cada usuario.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow Español, en esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/420585/hacer-un-sort-a-un-array-con-mongoose) utilizan un esquema muy parecido a lo que necesitas implementar. Puede que sea de ayuda.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Relacion entre usuario(1) y (n)personajes en mongodb. Estaria bien de este modo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247633/relacion-entre-usuario1-y-npersonajes-en-mongodb-estaria-bien-de-este-modo)